# Sort order is ignored in Objectify query

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a GAE Entity called *MyFile*

```
public class MyFile {  
   static enum LocationEnum {Folders, Hidden};  
   static enum FileType {File, Folder);  
   @Id private Long id;  
   private Key<MyFile> parent;  
   private String name;  
   private LocationEnum location;  
   private FileType fType;

   // getters and setters  
}
```

And a function in a separate DAO class to query for files based on their parent, returning the results ordered by name.

```
public List<MyFile> getFiles(Key<MyFile> parent) {  
    Query<MyFile> q1 = ofy().query(MyFile.class).filter("parent", parent).filter("location", LocationEnum.Folders).order("name");  
    return q1.list();
}
```

It seems my order is ignored as the results are returned ordered by id. It did occur to me that I was missing something to do with indexing, but I noticed GAE blessed me an auto generated index based on location, parent, name. So I thought it would just work.

How do I order by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. It is not possible to do a case insensitive search on App Engine. GAE will order by upper case first A-Z followed by a-z.

Comment: Default orders by ASCII. That said, if you put a "-" for descending or "+" for ascending in from of "name" for order ("+name"), it might do the trick. However, I don't believe that will be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Objectify are you using ? Starting from Objectify4 all fields are **unindexed** by default. So you need to annotate necessary fields with [@Index](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/objectify/annotation/Index.java).

Comment: I'm using Objectify 3.1. I tried adding my own indexes to datastore-indexes.xml for the 'name' property but no luck. The 3 MyFile entities that exist have a name value of Testing (id 90), UserGuide.pdf (id 88) and defaultlogo.png (id 87). Am I correct in expecting them to be returned in alphabetical order starting with defaultlogo.png?

Comment: This is odd. Do you see `name` field when you view entity in development datastore viewer ?

Comment: Yep, I see name in the datastore viewer. The values are as per the previous comment. Do I need to include name as a filter in order to sort by name?

Comment: And changing the order parameter to '-name' instead of 'name' returns the entities in the opposite order of 1) defaultlogo.png 2) UserGuide.pdf 3) Testing.